# Router password generation - why do vendors use SSID / Router ID?

Tags: passwords, key-generation, router

[We know](https://deadcode.me/blog/2016/07/01/UPC-UBEE-EVW3226-WPA2-Reversing.html) - for example - that UPC did use the Routers Serial Number and its SSID to generate the default password for a specific router.

My question is: Why go through the hassle to correlate the password with publicly available data? Wouldn't a factory wide counter that just +1s every password and starts over when overflowing be a much more secure way of doing things (The password still correlates to the router ID in some way, but at least not to the SSID AND the router ID).

I know that this is still not sufficient for a safe password - but why would you start doing ['magic'](https://haxx.in/upc_keys.c) if the outcome is basically the same - if not even worse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because to make manufacturing simple. Instead of having to create a custom firmware for each product, the firmware just reads the ROM where the MAC or serial is stored, to calculate the password. Same with the SSID.

This means the circuits containing firmware, can be shipped pre-loaded to the factory, and the only personalization done is assigning its MAC ID, from which the serial number is usually derived too.

This also means machines that print stickers and such, only need to be supplied with the router's MAC ID and then they can calculate the password out.

Some router manufacturers have started using more secure password generation algorithms like using a HMAC to calculate the password, which usually means you cannot deduce the password by just reverse-engineering the function, but you need to actually reverse-engineer the firmware. (where the secret "master golden key" is stored)

Routers shipped by ISPs can however be 'provisioned' from the ISP's server. These are usually shipped with a blank password (unprotected network), and wifi disabled, but as soon as they touch the internet and get the config filename from the DHCP, they will download a configuration file, where the wifi password is usually the same password as the customer uses to login to its customer portal.

As you might know, in mass-production, it's very hard or expensive to "personalize" a device, instead each device must be as similar as possible.
The ideal situation is where the device is "personalized" by the customer.

Comment: Indeed, the factor of mass production and the inconvenience of communicating with the router for printing stickers didn't come to my mind. Thanks!

Comment: That's good reasoning, but there is one more: big companies and manufacturers do not care about security. They only advertise that they do.

Comment: @Overmind I don't agree. Look at safe locks, are they shipped with a random code? Nope, they are shipped with the default combo of 1-2-3-4-5-6 or 50-25-50 for rotational ones. Then the end user has a responsibility to change the combo. Same applies to router. It isn't "insecure" to ship a router with a default password or no password at all, as long as its possible for the end user to set/change the password.

Comment: Well, why not have a random code stamped on a label for locks ? Users could still change them, but they won't be default. Same for routers. Why do g-mail and yahoo do not have a direct logout button and why do they have 'remember' option enabled by default ? This is intentionally done !

Comment: @Overmind as I written in this answer, it makes manufacturing much simpler. When manufacturing pin tumbler locks, pins are usually paired with the key, and a empty lock is manufactured, and then a manual operator "loads" the paired pins for a specific key into the lock housing. Do you understand how much more expensive equipment would be if they should be "personalized" at the factory? When the combo is so easily changed, why go the hassle of assigning unique combos then? For gmail/yahoo, its to increase convience. Its your fault if you do not UNCHECK the remember me button.

Comment: And keyed safe locks is same here, as they are changeable, its easier to manufacturer them with a "blank" key setting, ship a key blank with the safe and then ship the real key with the safe inside a sealed envelope. Then locks and keys do not need to be paired. And if the user is then so stupid so he uses the safe with the key blank programmed, instead of reprogramming the lock after the key in the envelope, he has himself to blame. Where did the responsibility of the end user go?